# Обращение к открытому ранее окну браузера

Tags: javascript

На странице есть несколько ссылок. И при нажатии на них открывается новое окно методом .open(). У каждой ссылки свое уникальное окно.
Если при повторном нажатии на ранее нажатую ссылку, то новое окно не откроется, так как окно уже было открыто и фокус на него перейдет.

Но если обновить или закрыть и потом заново открыть ту страницу со ссылками, и после этого опять нажать на ранее нажатую ссылку то опять откроется новое окно.

Как с помощью JavaScript определить, что уже есть открытое окно нажатой ссылки, чтобы не загружать страничку заново?

Вот JS код:

```
var app01Window;
var app02Window;

function openApp(url){
    if(url == 'menu1'){
        if ((!app01Window)||app01Window.closed) {
            app01Window = window.open( 'http://'+url, '_blank', 'Width=960, Height=535');
        }
        app01Window.focus();
    }
    if(url == 'menu2'){
        if ((!app02Window)||app02Window.closed) {
            app02Window = window.open( 'http://'+url, '_blank', 'Width=960, Height=535');
        }
        app02Window.focus();
    }
}
```

Вот ссылки:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openApp('menu1');">Menu 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="openApp('menu2');">Menu 2</a>
```

Comment: Вообще возможно ли хоть как-то определить такое?

Comment: вторым параметром можно передать имя окна.... `window.open(url, name, params)`..... где-то хранить, а потом искать по имени

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как извлечь имя, т.е. 2 параметр и как потом по нему искать?

Comment: `var window_1 = window.open(url, name, params);` в `window_1` будет ссылка на окно...... дальше через `window_1` можно манипулировать.... а также можно её положить в `localStorage` (если окно вдруг закроют, то при открытии можно достать из `localStorage` значение и произвести необходимые манипуляции по блокировке ссылки и чего у вас там)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не могли бы Вы примерный код написать если можно, я сам в JS пока плохо разбираюсь

Comment: Народ есть у кого нибудь еще идеи?

Comment: @Xfirab ссылки в одном домене находятся?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранять текущий статус в *куки* или *localStorage*.

В примере ниже используется `localStorage`. Сохраняем `true` при повторном нажатии если флаг выставлен то не даем создавать новые окна.

```
function openApp(url) {
    if (url == 'menu1' && !(localStorage.app01Window == 'true')) {
        if (!app01Window || app01Window.closed) {
            app01Window = window.open('http://' + url, 'menu1', 'Width=960, Height=535');
            localStorage.app01Window = "true";
        }
        app01Window.focus();
    }
    if (url == 'menu2' && !(localStorage.app02Window == "true")) {
        if (!app02Window || app02Window.closed) {
            app02Window = window.open('http://' + url, 'menu2', 'Width=960, Height=535');
            localStorage.app02Window = "true";
        }
        app02Window.focus();
    }
}
```

Для того чтобы установить флаг в `false`, нужно добавить на открываемые странички следующий код:

```
window.onunload = function () {
    localStorage.app02Window = "false";
};
```

Comment: Codd Wrench ссылки в разных доменах находятся

Comment: я не понял Ваш код, он же закрывает окна

Comment: @Xfirab, хм, прошу прощения, я параллельно отвечал на другой вопрос и задачи перемешались.